# Nesting Dropdown inside Step in Ant Design

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I use an Ant Design `<Steps>` Component on my website.

In addition, I also want to have a `<Dropdown>` Component applied in my last `<Step>`, something like this:

```
<Steps current={1}>
  <Step title="Finished" description="This is a description." />
  <Step title="In Progress" subTitle="Left 00:00:08" description="This is a description." />
  <Dropdown overlay={myOwnDropdownWithLinks}>
    <Step title="Waiting" description="This is another description." />
  </Dropdown>
</Steps>
```

I can't assign a `<Dropdown>` Component inside a `<Steps>` Component, so I'm looking for a workaround for this behavior.

How can I assign a dropdown to a particular step? Is it possible to nest these kinds of components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [Steps API](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step)

Props:

- description:  Description of the step, optional
- icon:         Icon of the step, optional
- title:        Title of the step
- subTitle:     Subtitle of the step

They all have the type of `string|ReactNode`, this means you can directly pass the JSX component to them via those props.

```
<Step title={<StepDropdown />} />
```

---

Example:

[image]

```
import { Steps, Menu, Dropdown } from "antd";
import { DownOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
const { Step } = Steps;

const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>A</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>B</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>C</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

const StepDropdown = () => {
  return (
    <Dropdown overlay={menu}>
      <a className="ant-dropdown-link" onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}>
        Hover me <DownOutlined />
      </a>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Steps current={1}>
      <Step title={<StepDropdown />} description="This is a description." />
      <Step title="In Progress" description="This is a description." />
      <Step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." />
    </Steps>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Basic - Ant Design Demo]

Comment: It works like a charm! The type of the props were the key, thanks!